# CSS repeating background fixed in relation to centered html content?

Tags: html, css

My webpage has content that is contained in a box of fixed size that is always centered, and a repeating background image filling the rest of the viewport. I would like the repeating background to maintain it's relationship to the content box no matter how I resize the browser window. Can this be done with CSS only?

Comment: Can you post HTML & CSS preferably in a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) (or something similar)?

Comment: Like this?: http://jsfiddle.net/5kmb2/

Comment: And you want the `body` repeating background to stay centered?

Answer (score 2):

If you use `background-position` you can fix the background to a particular spot, in this case, horizontally centered as your `#main-wrap` is.

http://jsfiddle.net/5kmb2/1/

```
body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    background-image: url(http://rturngames.com/images/plethora_bkgnd.png);
    background-repeat: repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: 50% 0; /* NEW LINE */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yea, set the background-position to center:

```
background-image: url(http://rturngames.com/images/plethora_bkgnd.png);
background-repeat:repeat;
background-position:center;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5kmb2/2/